# can connect to mongodb via shell but not via mongoid

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoid

I have a ruby script that connect to mongodb using mongoid. It works fine on my local machine with a passwordless mongodb server, but when I try to run it on a client's server, their mongodb requires authentication, and in spite of getting connected with the correct auth params in the mongoid.yml, I still get an error.

This is the `mongoid.yml` file

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: dbname
      user: root
      password: secret
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        safe: true
```

I'm loading it like this in Ruby:

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("/path/to/mongoid.yml", :development)
```

And this is the error I get when I run the script. Note that the error is actually triggered not at the moment of loading the yml file, but at the point where I try to issue my first Mongoid query a few lines below.

```
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@gemsetname/gems/moped-1.5.0/lib/moped/node.rb:382:in `block in query': The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query (Moped::Errors::QueryFailure)
  @length=153
  @request_id=2
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[:slave_ok]
  @full_collection_name="dbname.items_collection"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={"$query"=>{"detected_on"=>2013-06-19 00:00:00 UTC, "url"=>"http://www.example.com/"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 10057: "unauthorized db:dbname ns:dbname.items_collection lock type:0 client:127.0.0.1"
```

As a final note the username and password in the yml file are good, because I am fully able to connect to my mongodb shell with them:

```
$ mongo dbname -u root -p 'secret'
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: dbname
> show collections
system.indexes
system.users
>
```

Comment: Your exact code snippets work perfectly fine for me. Is the query that's failing above connecting to a different database that perhaps your user doesn't have access too (eg. dbname.items_collection)? Or does that collection live in the same database you're authenticating against?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, I believe it is because you have to specify the authentication database.
Trying looking at this: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config